# How to use case in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have to display Datetime in my gridview, the problem is that while I am inserting values to the database, for default date I am passing "1/1/1900", so when retrieving the data I found the value "01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM" in gridview.

If the datetime is "01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM" I want it as a null value or the corresponding date, can I check this in a stored procedure? Pls help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DateField = '01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM' THEN NULL
        ELSE DateField
    END AS DateField
FROM
   Wherever
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of storing default date you can set the date as null when inserting to avoid future mistakes and use like.why to make things messy just use

```
Select ISNULL(DateField,'what everyou want to show in Grid when NULL') as DateField From YOURTABLE
```

OR

```
Select DateField from YOURTABLE
```